# regex expression for finding sql expression within Java string

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to find a substring within a string that is like "upper(someName)".  But it may be written as "upper ( someName )", basically might have one or more embedded spaces.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the result of your attempts?

Answer (score 0):

try this pattern :

```
".*upper\\( * .+ *\\).*"
```